# MAAS: 18.04LTS gets different routes than on 16.04LTS -- how to change route metrics

Tags: 16.04, networking, 18.04, maas

I am provisioning machines with MAAS, and the machines are all configured with two different subnets:

1. public network 9.9.9.0/24. publicly routable subnet. (9.9.9.0 is redacted). DHCP.
2. private network 192.168.79.0/24. Maas management network (auto-assign).

Keeping the same interface configuration in MAAS across all nodes, when I deploy on 18.04LTS, the routing table is different than when I deploy 16.04LTS, out of the box. The way it's setup, the 18.04 nodes essentially prevent connections from networks outside (1) and (2). e.g. I can't ssh nor ping the 18.04 host from the public internet. Everything's fine on 16.04 hosts.

From both 16.04 and 18.04 hosts, I can successfully connect *TO* the public internet (e.g. `wget google.com`), and I get responses.

The routing table on 18.04 ends up being slightly different than the one on 16.04:

```
# 18.04 machine has IPs 9.9.9.9 (eno1), and 192.168.79.9 (eno2)
ubuntu@18-04:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.79.254  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eno2
0.0.0.0         9.9.9.254       0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eno1
192.168.79.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno2
9.9.9.0         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno1
9.9.9.254       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 eno1
```

On 16.04:

```
ubuntu@16-04:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         9.9.9.254       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eno1
192.168.79.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno2
9.9.9.0         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno1
```

The one on 18.04 doesn't work properly. I'm not sure why there's an extra host route (UH) added, and the preferential route is via eno2 (the private network). I can see incoming internet packets come in over eno1 (with tcpdump -i eno1), but I'm guessing the replies go back onto eno2 and get lost.

Is there a way to configure MAAS so 18.04 routing tables look like the ones on 16.04?

*UPDATE:*

18.04 uses netplan to configure networks, and it has special rules for dhcp. network config is in /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml , and netplan gives priority to the static route over the one aquired via dhcp.

I've had to reverse that priority assignment, but the only way I've managed to fix this is by patching the netplan files after deployment.

```
eno1:
    dhcp4: true
    match:
        macaddress: c8:1f:66:c9:fd:3c
    mtu: 1500
    set-name: eno1
eno2:
    addresses:
    - 192.168.79.110/24
    gateway4: 192.168.79.254
    match:
        macaddress: c8:1f:66:c9:fd:3d
    mtu: 1500
    nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 192.168.79.10
        - 192.168.79.11
        search:
        - maas
    set-name: eno2
```

My initial idea was to create an override file with a lexicographically greater name in /etc/netplan/, to remove the "gateway4" entry, but I don't think there's any way to *delete* a key. You can just override them. So I've edited the same file in place to add the route and give it a higher metric than the default 100 for dhcp networks.

Here's my patched route for eno2. eno1 (dhcp) stays unchanged.

```
eno1:
    dhcp4: true
    match:
        macaddress: ca:fe:ba:be:ca:3c
    mtu: 1500
    set-name: eno1
eno2:
    addresses:
    - 192.168.79.110/24
    # no need for this. use routes below.
    # gateway4: 192.168.79.254
    routes:
      - to: 0.0.0.0/0
        via: 192.168.79.254
        # dhcp gateways get 100 by default. make this > 100
        metric: 200
    match:
        macaddress: ca:fe:ba:be:ca:3d
    mtu: 1500
    nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 192.168.79.10
        - 192.168.79.11
        search:
        - maas
    set-name: eno2
```

I considered also making the dhcp gw route metric 0 (with dhcp4-overrides), but then both gateway routes would have had priority 0 -- and I'm fuzzy on the linux rules then.

`netplan apply` with the updated config gets me where I want.

Is there any way to make that edit as part of the automated deployment in MAAS?

Comment: Maybe this is the same as this one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042582/how-to-set-default-route-with-netplan-ubuntu-18-04-server-2-nic?noredirect=1&lq=1

netplan is at play. my private network is dhcp, so netplan assigns it a default metric of 100

Comment: Possible workaround: https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1596522